# Perl regexp partial match if the string were longer?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a tree of nested hashes, each of which contains a name, like nested directories with files.  If I get foreign supplied regexps at runtime (which I don't want to analyze) how can I find in which subtrees to look for matches.  The path to match might be of the form

```
"$x{name}/$x{subdir}{name}/$x{subdir}{subdir}{name}"
```

but, because there can be thousands of hashes, I want to try it only if both of these partially match:

```
"$x{name}"
"$x{name}/$x{subdir}{name}"
```

Or even better, if the 1st part matches then try to continue directly with the 2nd and then with the 3rd, sort of like `/\G.../g`, except the regexp comes from elsewhere in one piece.  And I'd need backtracking to also look in all other partially matching subdirs.

[PCRE g_match_info_is_partial_match](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html#g-match-info-is-partial-match) sounds just what I'm looking for, but despite the "Perl" in that name even the 5.18 source doesn't seem to contain this.  And I actually want something backward compatible to 5.8.0.

Background to this question is introducing regexp syntax to [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/).  We essentially do that for patterns, but due to their trivial syntax, that is easy.  Note that we cache what files we find and can cope with more files as they appear.  This enables makepp to match files which might be built later, because it puts the rules' outputs into the tree as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perl regexes and PCRE inspire each other, but are not really compatible and are totally not the same. Perl uses a custom regex engine.

Either a regex matches, or it doesn't. If a regex fails, it is impossible to tell where the match failed except when the regex was written in such a way to report the position.

The only viable solution would be to require a list of regexes, one for each level.

Otherwise you could require users to write regexes in such a way that partial matches work as well. In this case, the regex `qr|foo/bar\.txt$|` would have to be rewritten

```
qr|\A /                # anchor at start
  (?: [^/]*/       )*  # match as many directories as neccessary
  (?: foo/bar\.txt )?  # maybe match an ending foo/bar.txt
\z|x                   # anchor at end
```

Example:

```
for ("/a/", "/a/b/", "/a/b/foo/", "/a/b/foo/bar.txt", "/a/b/foo/baz.txt", "/a/bar.txt") {
  say qq("$_" -- ), /$regex/ ? "matches" : "doesn't match";
}
```

Output:

```
"/a/" -- matches
"/a/b/" -- matches
"/a/b/foo/" -- matches
"/a/b/foo/bar.txt" -- matches
"/a/b/foo/baz.txt" -- doesn't match
"/a/bar.txt" -- doesn't match
```

Obviously, this doesn't reduce the search space in any way for this regex.

You may be able to spin this in a way that works for your application. Depending on the guarantees your app provides, you can transform the original regex automatically to something that “always” matches.

Comment: I've also been thinking along the lines of your last sentence.  But that would mean analyzing the regexp, a daunting task with all the nice look-aheads and -behinds and what not.  Or append an inverse `.*` to the string to be matched.  Except I can think of no way how that could be possible...